# how to override WPF Theme style for a single button

Tags: wpf, styles, themes

I succesfully apply a theme to my WPF app.

Now I need a specific button to style in a totally different way but I cannot override what the theme applies.

How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried using a <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButtonStyle"> ... </Style> In your resources? I'm pretty sure this will override your theme if you assign a button to this style.

Comment: @MikeEason it works, however how can i apply that style only on a specific named control? is there something like TargetName?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You will need to set the Style attribute on your button as a reference to your style. <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two styles. One you already create for all buttons in your application. Now create another style but put the key attribute to it and assign it to your specific buttons.

In your App.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"> <!-- This is for generic button -->
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
</Style>
```

Now its time for your specific button:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="specificButton"> <!-- This is for specific button -->
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
</Style>
```

In your Page or UserControl:

```
<Button Width="200" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
<Button Style="{StaticResource specificButton}" Width="200" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
```

Hope it helps.